# Which files do I need to deploy a nodeJS app on web

Tags: node.js, web

I'm a beginner and I'm trying to deploy my nodeJS app, which works locally, on web. I'm using Jelastic cloud. I've create a environnement. Now when I want to deploy from local file, I must give a .zip file.

[image: My app file looks like that].

I've tried to compress it in .gif and use this .gif. Jelastic said that deployment is a success but then he failed starting the server.

So I want to know if it is the good file to give and also I'm not sure of what should stand on the package.json (actually there is only the dependencies (and name and version)).
In addition I'm not sure of which parameters I must give to server.listen on my server file.

I'll also be happy if you have any other advise to give.
I've also tried on heroku, it return a npm ERR : missing script:start

there is the code :

server.js :

```js
var http=require("http");

var express = require('express');
var app =express();
var mainServer=http.createServer(app);
var fs = require('fs');
var io =require('socket.io'). listen(mainServer);
var users=[];
var waitingRoomSize=0;
var readyToPlay=[];
var nbUser=0;
var accounts = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(__dirname+'/accounts.json',{encoding:'utf8'},function(err){if(err){throw err;}}));
var clockOfGames = 0;
//var p=0;
var TimePassing = setInterval(function(){clockOfGames++},50);
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.set('views', __dirname);

function account(_pseudo,_mdp){
   ...
}
function user(pseudo,id,_mainId){
...
}
  app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html');
  });


app.get('/onGamePage/:mId',function(req, res){
    var x = String(req.params.mId).substring(0,11);
    if (x=='heavenStone'){
    var prm = req.params.mId;
    res.render('onGamePage.html',{mainId:prm});
    }
});

app.get('/index/:mId',function(req, res){
    var x = String(req.params.mId).substring(0,11);
    if (x=='heavenStone'){
    var prm = req.params.mId;
    res.render('index.html',{mainId:prm});
    }
});


app.use(express.static(__dirname+"/style/"));

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){
    
...
});





  

mainServer.listen(80);
```

Package.json :

```js
{
    "name": "TM",
    "start":"node server.js",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "dependencies": {
        "ejs": "^2.6.1",
        "ent": "~0.1.0",
        "express": "^3.21.2",
        "fs": "0.0.1-security",
        "mysql": "^2.16.0",
        "node-mysql-admin": "^0.1.5",
        "nodeadmin": "^0.1.2",
        "socket.io": "^1.2.1"
    },
    "author": "Lenny"
}
```

and then there is some html.

Comment: Hi, there is no node_modules folder, Did you run npm install command?

Comment: eh.. no, I'm not sure where I have to do that...

Comment: Did you followed the https://jelastic.com/blog/nodejs-hosting-paas/ blog?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: I do but I don't really understood. I actually don't know what to do, I have my deployment which return a error 502 when I try to use the link, what should stand in node_module folder and where can I run commands?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was on the package.json file. That's how it looks now :

```js
{
    "scripts":{
        "start": "node app.js"
    },
    "name": "TM",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "dependencies": {
        "ejs": "^2.6.1",
        "ent": "~0.1.0",
        "express": "^3.21.2",
        "fs": "0.0.1-security",
        "socket.io": "^1.2.1"
    },
    "author": "Lenny"
}
```

However I still haven't fully understand jelastic, I can run it by starting in the console and I'm not allowed to run it on port 80, don't understand why.

Comment: Please specify how you install the application. It is deployed by clicking a button "Deploy" without any additional actions as shown in the deployment guide (http://docs.jelastic.com/deployment-guide). If you deploys it manually by command line (WebSSH, SSH etc) - you starts second server in container and you should use different port.

Comment: I deploy it by clicking the button deploy, I use a zip file and it is the only server in the environment. The logs return : “Starting nodejs server: [FAILED]“. I can start it through the ssh console with: node ROOT/TM/app.js (TM is the name of the .zip file),then it works perfectly but the server turn off when I quit the console.

Answer (score 0):

For deploying NodeJS apps I suggest you to use a PaaS services, like Heroku.

But before deploying an app you should create it ;)

These are some best practice when creating new NodeJS projects:

- Create a folder for your project and `cd` into that folder;
- Type `npm init` to generate your project initial files (such as package.json). It will ask you some information, you can fill what you want or simply press enter on each entry;
- Now you can start to create your project, with files and folders. Make sure to create a file called `app.js` or `index.js` in the main folder. It will be your app entry point;
- In package.json set this file as the start script:

  ```
  "scripts": {
      "start": "NODE_ENV=production node app.js"
  }
  ```
- Every time you will install a new dependency from NPM, make sure to install it as follow: `npm install --save packagename`. It will save dependency in your package.json file.
- Now it's time to deploy on Heroku, or another PaaS service. To do so, you must have installed GIT, you can download it and install, it's very simple.
- Follow this guide on Heroku to deploy: [DEPLOY ON HEROKU](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git)

Comment: `--save` is the default nowadays

Comment: My app is already created, when I start it (node app.js) in the terminal, in works (with localhost:XX) in the nav. So now I want to deploy it with jelastic cloud but I actually don't understand anything.

Comment: I've tried with heroku, it doesn't work. it return npm error missing script start. My package.json contain "start":"node server.js", so I don't understand the error.